# Python tuple operations and count

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have the following tuple.I want to build a string which outputs as stated in output.I want count all the elements corresponding to 'a' i.e, how many k1  occured w.r.t 'a' and so  on .What is the easiest way to do this

```
a=[('a','k1'),('b','k2'),('a','k2'),('a','k1'),('b','k2'),('a','k1'),('b','k2'),('c','k3'),('c','k4')]
```

Output should be in a string output=""

```
 a k1  3
 a k2  1
 b k1  1
 b k2  3
 c k3  1
 c k4  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the addition portion easily with [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).  The default dict works like a normal dictionary, except it has a default value for empty key stores so you can easily increment your counter when you iterate over your data set.

```
a=[('a','k1'),('b','k2'),('a','k2'),('a','k1'),('b','k2'),('a','k1'),('b','k2'),('c','k3'),('c','k4')]
from collections import defaultdict
b = defaultdict(int)
for item in a:
    b[item] += 1

print b
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('a', 'k2'): 1, ('c', 'k3'): 1, ('b', 'k2'): 3, ('a', 'k1'): 3, ('c', 'k4'): 1})
```

And for pretty printing it, just iterate over the resulting data and print it how you want.

```
for key, value in b.iteritems():
    print '%s %s %s' % (key[0], key[1], value)
```

Comment: collections.Counter is better suited here

Comment: @gnibbler :How is counter better suited .This also works pretty well right.For the output i loop for the second time in both the case.What advantages will i have with counter

Comment: `Counter` is purely suited towards counting unique bits of information. So if all you want to do is count occurences, then yes, `Counter` is better suited.

Comment: @Rajeev, this is such a common pattern with the defaultdict that it was added to the collections module and called Counter. There is a performance advantage of course, but it is also clearer in the code that something is being _counted_

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from `collections`:

```
>>> a = [('a', 'k1'), ('b', 'k2'), ('a', 'k2'), ('a', 'k1'), ('b', 'k2'), ('a', 'k1'), ('b', 'k2'), ('c', 'k3'), ('c', 'k4')]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(a)
Counter({('b', 'k2'): 3, ('a', 'k1'): 3, ('a', 'k2'): 1, ('c', 'k3'): 1, ('c', 'k4'): 1})
```

You can use `c.items()` to iterate over the counts:

```
>>> for item in c.items():
...     print(item)
... 
(('a', 'k2'), 1)
(('c', 'k3'), 1)
(('b', 'k2'), 3)
(('a', 'k1'), 3)
(('c', 'k4'), 1)
```

The above code is Python 3. The `Counter` class is new in Python 2.7. You can now rearrange the items in the desired order and convert them to a string if needed.